# Rspec for testing the rendered template outside of controller/view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, ruby-on-rails-5, rspec-rails, renderer

I have a situation to render a HTML template outside of controller(A class under service/lib directory) and I am rendering the template using the below code.

```
class SomeClass
   def some_method
      @template = ApplicationController.render(
            template: 'template',
            layout: mailer_template,
        )
   end
end
```

Is there any ways to test if the rendered template is the expected one and whether render happened during that method call?

**EDIT**

```
class BatchSendingService < AbstractController::Base

    require 'abstract_controller'

    include AbstractController::Rendering
    include AbstractController::AssetPaths
    include AbstractController::Helpers
    include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers


    include ActionView::Rendering
    include ActionView::ViewPaths
    include ActionView::Layouts
    self.view_paths = "app/views"

    def send_batch_email(mail, domain)
       @project = mail.project
       @client = Mailgun::Client.new ENV['MAILGUN_API_KEY']
       batch_message = Mailgun::BatchMessage.new(@client, domain)
       batch_message.from(from_data)

       mailer_layout = get_mailer_layout(mail.layout)
       mail_html = render(
          template: 'send_batch_email',
          layout: mailer_layout
      )

       batch_message.body_html(mail_html.to_s)

      batch_message.add_recipient(:to, recipient_email, {})
      response = batch_message.finalize 
   end
```

**EDIT**

`obj= BatchSendingService.new
      allow(obj).to receive(:render)
      BatchSendingService.send_batch_email(mail, domain)
      expect(obj) .to have_received(:render)
                        .with({ template: "template", layout: "layout" })`

By using the class where the instance method is called, the error is gone.

Comment: rspec has mailer specs https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/mailer-specs

Comment: There are too many locals and other styles in the layout/template which is being rendered. So It would be nice if I can able to check whether the calling method rendered the layout. Can you explain how to test this with mailer spec?, FYI: This method sending batch sending API.

Answer (score 0):

ActionController.render is a well tested method. The Rails Core Team saw to that. There's no need to test that it does what it says it does.

Rather, what you want to do is to make sure you called `ActionController.render` with the right parameters, using mock objects, like this:

```
describe SomeClass do
  subject(:some_class) { described_class.new }

  describe '#some_method' do
    let(:template) { 'template' }
    let(:layout) { 'mailer_template' }

    before do
      allow(ActionController).to receive(:render)

      some_class.some_method
    end

    it 'renders the correct template' do
      expect(ActionController)
        .to have_received(:render)
        .with({ template: template, layout: layout })
    end
  end
end
```

**EDIT**

Given the edited post, here's how I would approach the test. Note that not all of the code in your `send_batch_email` method is visible in your edit. So, YMMV:

```
describe BatchSendingService do
  subject(:batch_sending_service) { described_class.new }

  describe '#send_batch_email' do
    subject(:send_batch_email) do 
      batch_sending_service.send_batch_email(email, domain)
    end

    let(:email) { 'email' }
    let(:domain) { 'domain' }
    let(:batch_message) do
      instance_double(
        Mailgun::BatchMessage, 
        from: true,
        body_html: true,
        add_recipient, true,
        finalize: true
      )
    end
    let(:template) { 'send_batch_template' }
    let(:layout) { 'layout' }

    before do
      allow(Mailgun::Client).to receive(:new)
      allow(Mailgun::BatchMessage)
        .to receive(:new)
        .and_return(batch_message)
      allow(batch_sending_service)
        .to receive(:render)

      send_batch_email
    end

    it 'renders the correct template' do
      expect(batch_sending_service)
        .to have_received(:render)
        .with(template, layout)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Getting error like `RSpec::Mocks::MockExpectationError: #<ActionController::Base:0x007fb9698b6f30 @_action_has_layout=true, @_routes=nil, @_request=nil, @_response=nil> expected to have received render, but that object is not a spy or method has not been stubbed`

Comment: `allow(ActionController).to receive(:render)` sets up that mock. Notice that it is mocking `ActionController` not `ActionController::Base`. If the class under test is actually calling `ActionController::Base`, you'll need to mock that class. Feel free to post a more complete code sample in your question and I'll take another look.

Comment: Looks like the message `.render` is being sent to the `BatchSendingService` class. Substituting `BatchSendingService` for `ApplicationController` in my answer above should do the trick.

Comment: Yes, the error is gone, But the render method is not called it seems `(#<BatchSendingService:0x007fba59b1fe70 @_action_has_layout=true, @_routes=nil>).render({:template=>"template", :layout=>"layout"})
           expected: 1 time with arguments: ({:template=>"template", :layout=>"layout"})
           received: 0 times`